# Datatables fixed header shows up twice when scrolling

Tags: javascript, datatables

Has anyone experience this before?? 
It only happens after I reinitialize the table again

```
 if (typeof dataTable === 'undefined') { // if the table doesn't exist

    LoadIt(startdate, enddate)

} else { // if the table exist delete table

      $("#mytable_wrapper").remove();
      $(".mytable_wrapper").dataTable().fnDestroy();
      LoadIt(startdate, enddate)
}
```

Here is a screenshot[image]

It disapears after I resize my browser or after I open developer tools

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I fixed by adding table-layout: fixed to the table